# Foundation 4 vs Bootstrap 3 for a responsive analytics Dashboard

Tags: css, d3.js, sass, css-frameworks

We are considering using Angular/Ember js for a dashboard which will primarily have d3 graphs for server monitoring/analytics. The goal is to start developing with a responsive workflow in place and hence the question of Foundation 4 vs Bootstrap 3. (I know bootstrap 3 is not out yet but we are considering to start out with it now). Much appreciate any insight of which Foundation/bootstrap could fit in better.

Comment: Check out this website: http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php  it breaks it down pretty nicely.  The biggest thing that has me reconsidering foundation 4 is Foundation 4 utilizes Zepto as a replacement for jQuery.